# Java : Two similar classes, one immutable - sharing code between them

Tags: java, class, immutability, sharing

Let's say I have two classes. Both have the same member fields (including the same names), but one class' member fields are declared as final (immutable), and the other is not. Most of the member methods will work for both classes.

How could I share the member methods of the immutable class with the other class (as if by inheritance or something) without having to copy the entire methods to the other class. I'm figuring there's no such way but I figured I'd ask first. Otherwise I'll just declare them in difference namespaces and give them the same class name. It should be noted that not ALL of the immutable class methods will work for the mutable one.

```
public class ImmutableDoubleLine {
    public final DoublePoint origin;
    public final DoublePoint endPoint;

    // ...

    public double getLength() {
        return origin.calcDistance(endPoint);
    }
}

    public class MutableDoubleLine {
        public DoublePoint origin;
        public DoublePoint endPoint;

        // ...

// same code as immutable class
        public double getLength() {
            return origin.calcDistance(endPoint);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, and this is very important.

Unless the class `DoublePoint` is internally immutable, and all it's instance variables down the line are internally immutable, all you have done with the `final DoublePoint origin` statement is make the **reference** to `origin` and `endpoint` where they can't be changed to point to different instances, you have **NOT** made `ImmutableDoubleLine` immutable.

I mention this because you don't show the code for `DoublePoint`.

Second, to your actual question, use an `Interface` and have both classes implement it:

```
public interface DoubleLine
{
    public double getLength();
}
```

I would try and make everything immutable as much as possible, it makes debugging easier and makes concurrency much easier as well.

Comment: DoublePoint is immutable. But that is outside the scope of the question. In the mutable DoubleLine, the points may be of a mutable type, also...

Comment: @WilliamtheCoderer many people, I would say most, even some "senior" developers don't understand that making a instance variable `final` doesn't make the object it points to immutable. `private final List l` doesn't make the `List` that `l` points to immutable, that is why I bring it up.

Comment: Yeah, the DoublePoint also declares its members (which are doubles) as final. They can't be changed. But in the mutable line class, it may use a double point that has points that can be changed. I just haven't got to that point yet. I only need the immutable versions right now. I want to be able to use the code to make a mutable version later for adding some editing ability.

Comment: @WilliamtheCoderer I would keep it immutable and just create new instances, creating objects is cheap in modern Java now, creating locks and other concurrency primatives and waiting on the isn't cheap.

Answer (score 2):

Use composition. Have one of the classes hold an instance of the other and pass the member methods through to the internal instance. This is kind of a facade class.

Answer (score 2):

Make them all inherit from an abstract class `AbstractDoubleLine`, add two abstract methods `getOrigin()` and `getEndPoint()` to this class, and implement all the common methods using these getters.

The getters for the immutable class should of course guarantee the immutability of the DoublePoint instances, either by making them immutable or by defensive copying.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you declare your fields public?

Just make them private and add setters only in the derived class. The Immutable class won't have setters and the fields have to be set in the constructor.

In this way you don't need to make DoublePoint final, but be careful that if you return them and are not final, you've to return a defensive copy of them.

Comment: In the immutable class it would make it much easier to make them public. In the mutable class they may be private. The concept remains the same though. I still would like to share the code between them, but only some of the methods.

Comment: and don't forget defensive copying when required

Comment: You've to do a little more work to create the getters (if needed) and the setter in the mutable class, but apart from that all code can be shared.

Comment: @ratchetfreak yes I was editing about that. I'm not sure that he wants to return the objects directly, but of course if he needs that, he needs to make a copy, otherwise another class may ask your DoublePoint with get and then start to modify their state. Unless they are Immutable, which they should probably be. In that case defensive copies are  not necessary.